# rendering partials within filters in middleman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, partial-views, middleman

I'd like to display a form within a `:php` filter in my Middleman Haml source file.  Here's what I've tried:

```
:php
  $someVar="#{= "my/partial"}"
```

It doesn't work.  How do I render a partial within a filter?  Simply outputting the value of a Ruby variable with the Haml code (rendered to HTML) would also be acceptable.